# Retrieving special characters using regular expressions

Tags: html, regex, vb.net

I am trying to retrieve some information from a website using regular expression. I ended up with an output containing  html entity for a special character.

For example, instead of `Côté` I am getting `C&ocirc;t&eacute`.

Please help in retrieving the actual string. TIA.

Comment: What language are you using? Why aren't you using a proper HTML parser?

Comment: Hello sir, I am using VB.net and the method is httprequest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HtmlDecode should work for you:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7c5fyk1k.aspx

```
s = HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(s)
```